# Symfony2 inserting incorrect date

Tags: php, date

I was trying to insert date in 'mm/dd/yy' format. But, when I insert the value got changed:

'10/28/2014' becomes '2016-04-10'

This is what I get when I var_dump entity object.

```
private 'lastPmtDate' => 
    object(DateTime)[724]
      public 'date' => string '2016-04-10 00:00:00' (length=19)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Asia/Kathmandu' (length=14)
```

When I change the format to 'yyyy-mm-dd' the date is inserted as it is. What is the solution for this ?

Comment: Please post the PHP code you're using, especially the part where you create the `DateTime` object.

Comment: Just don't! Don't insert date as any other format as `Y-m-d`.

Comment: How to deal with different dateformat ? What are the best practices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is default database `DATE` format and have nothing to do with Symfony. You should use output formatting either in query or in `twig` if you want `mm/dd/yy` format. Otherwise use different field type.